# Schottky diode for MOSFET H-bridge

Tags: mosfet, diodes, h-bridge, schottky

how can I calculate the value of the schottky diode?  I use 4 MOSFET N-channel IRF1404 instead of IRF510 in the schematic

The motor should withstand currents up to 100 A and 12v

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Ask yourself what the peak voltage the MOSFET(s) needs to block is. Consequently, what is the peak voltage the diodes needs to block? Now it gets trickier, what is the peak current the MOSFETs needs to conduct in reverse before you turn them off? Consequently, what is the peak current your diodes needs to conduct? Simulation can help your understanding a lot here.

Comment: Ricardo, if you are done with this Q and A please take [the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand the motivation for people providing free help. If you feel you can't accept an answer then raise a new comment under the appropriate answer to ask for clarification.

Comment: @Andyaka sorry, i forget this, solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *how can I calculate the value of the schottky diode?*

There are no schottky diodes in your circuit: -

[image]

If however you meant the 4 diodes I've ringed in blue circles then there is no need for them because each N channel MOSFET has a bulk diode inside the chip that performs exactly the same function as those external 1N4001 devices (D1, D2, D3 and Another D3): -

[image]